# Effectively handling Browser history and Back button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-plugins

**What I have:** 
A website that uses the following script to show pages:

```
var FluidNav = {
    init: function() {
        $("a[href*=#]").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
            if($(this).attr("href").split("#")[1]) {
                FluidNav.goTo($(this).attr("href").split("#")[1]);
            }
        });
        this.goTo("home");
    },
    goTo: function(page) {
        var next_page = $("#"+page);
        var nav_item = $('nav ul li a[href=#'+page+']');
        $("nav ul li").removeClass("current");
        nav_item.parent().addClass("current");
        FluidNav.resizePage((next_page.height() + 40), true, function() {
             $(".page").removeClass("current"); next_page.addClass("current"); 
        });
        $(".page").fadeOut(500);
        next_page.fadeIn(500);
```

When I click on a link, the URL in the URL bar doesn't change, but content is shown. There is no way to use the Browser Back button. The inner links are with `#hash` tags. EX: `abc.com/#home`, `abc.com/#services`. However, if I were to enter `abc.com/#services` in the URL bar, I would be redirected to the `#home` page.

**What I want to achieve:**
When I click on a link, the URL to change, and the browser to record that in its history. When I press the back button, the site to generate the content of the page I was previously to. 
When I open a new tab and enter `abc.com/#services`, to be sent to the `#services` page and not to the home page

**What I have tried**
These are the resources I have read and the solutions I have tried:

- Using the History.js method described here:
  https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/ I fill out all the steps and
  enter the scripts to the header, however only the URL in the URL bar
  changes when I click on a link. When I click the Back button, the URl
  changes accordingly, but content doesn't load. When I enter a URL in
  the URL bar, I get sent to the home page.
- Ajaxify and Gist method described here: https://github.com/browserstate/ajaxify
  Achieves the same as above, same issues as well
- Davis.js method described here: https://github.com/olivernn/davis.js
  Achieves nothing upon completion of the installation instructions. No change.
- jQuery BBQ Plugin method described here: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/
  Achieves nothing, no change upon loading the .js file in the header of the website.
- I read this article and understood it: http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html

It seems that despite my efforts there is something in the code that my website is using that is getting in the way of the methods described above.

Any advice is greatly appreciated on how to solve this.

Comment: Did you look at backbone's router? http://backbonejs.org/#Router

Comment: Is it because your onclick handler is doing 'preventDefault' so you're stopping the browser from handling the event and updating the browser history?  You have to let the browser receive the click event if you want to use its history feature.

Comment: @ClaudioFernandez I am giving it a go right now. I will post with results in a few.

Comment: @LeeKowalkowski Yes, that seems quite right. Its only that I don't know how to edit that part out and still have the content fade in and out. Any suggestions?

Comment: @ClaudioFernandez Well, backbone's Router didn't prove to be effective in my case,  unfrotunately. Any other suggestions, guys?

Comment: perhaps at the bottom of the `goTo` function, you can do `location.assign('#' + page);`  I don't read jQuery too well, since I hardly actually use it.

Comment: @LeeKowalkowski Just gave that a try, and without any of the other methods above, it achieves the functionality of changing the URL, but still it doesn't load content when pressing the back button. Perhaps I should remove some of the lines including and after  e.preventDefault();?

Comment: You need to listen for changes to location.hash if you want to enable the back button.  In jQuery, that would be `$(window).hashchange`.